# setAttribute "value" returns undefined

Tags: javascript

I am dynamically (but not async) building html elements with js and encounter an error upon setting the "value" attribute.
Simplified code:

```
 let tag = document.createElement("div");
      tag.innerHTML = `${item}`;
      tag.setAttribute("value", `${item}`); 
      tag.classList.add("newtags", "lot of css classes")
      tagslist.appendChild(tag)


    newtags = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.newtags'))
    newtags.forEach(item => {
       item.addEventListener("click", e =>{
        console.log(e.target.value)
    })
  })
```

Upon clicking on the created tags I get "undefined" yet if I do console.log(e.target) without adding value I can see it is working and the value is there. Am I setting something that isn't really the value of the element?
Thanks

Comment: I have to ask something from you, you said somewhere in the comments on your question that you used sqlite in dev. And Postgre in production, so is it possible?

Comment: Sorry Sunderam I don't think I understand your question, Django upon initialization of a project creates an unmigrated sqlite db, not the best fit for production. When putting in prod the most common choice is to use PGSql for Django projects since it behaves more or less the same as a sqlite db and is supported by Django ORM

Comment: Well, I know that, but sometimes it's become difficult to change db, although thanks for reply :)

Comment: If it can help, what I do is that I have a manage.py file and manage.prod.py that look into different settings files upon migration, staticfile dirs, etc. I work in the dev environment, migrating only when necessary for the prod file and using fixtures sometimes. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`div` element doesn't have `value` property. only few elements such as `input`, `textarea` have `value`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

Answer (score 2):

[Div elements don't have value attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div#attributes). Only form controls (like input and button elements) do.

You could use a [data attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) for this **but div elements aren't designed to be interactive**.

You are adding a click event handler but screen readers won't tell the user they can click on them, and people navigating with a keyboard will skip right past them since you haven't done anything to allow them to be focused.

Use a `button` instead of a `div`. Apply CSS as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to add attribute `data-value` to the div as `div` element doesn't have a value attribute.

```
tag.setAttribute("data-value", `${item}`);
```

Then when you try to get the div data value.

```
console.log(e.target.dataset.value)
```